# How to embed facebook / twitter login into my site asynchronously

Tags: ajax, twitter, facebook-login

I want my site users to be able to login using facebook/ twitter login. I found the code from facebook/twitter developer page. This is working fine. But i wish to implement these code through asynchronous(ajax) request. Something very similar to http://list.ly login window.